# How can I add expansions to a bash argument

Tags: bash, shell, find, arguments

I have this simple script to find a file on a folder, with "find" command in the shell works, but in the script doesn't.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ""
read -p "-Write file you need- " FILE
read -p "-Write the folder to search- " FOLDER

FILE="'*$FILE*'"

find $FOLDER -name $FILE
```

If "FILE" is "test" I want to be '*test *' so find can find not only the same name of file, also test.txt and more.

EDIT:

I'm using #!/bin/bash -ex that tell me what's happen in every line of code, if I add

echo $FILE

Its tell me this:

```
echo $FILE
```

'* test *'

```
find "$FOLDER" -name "$FILE"
```

find /home -name ' ' \ ' ' *test * '\ ' ' '

I don't know why It's adding so many quoting marks and not using the same content of variable like echo

Comment: Try `find "$FOLDER" -name "*$FILE*"` without reassigning the variable `FILE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes where they are needed, like this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ""
read -p "-Write file you need- " FILE
read -p "-Write the folder to search- " FOLDER

FILE="*$FILE*"

set -x
find "$FOLDER" -name "$FILE"
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I'm using #!/bin/bash -ex that tell me what's happen in every line of code, if I add
echo $FILE

Its tell me this:

echo $FILE
'*test*'
find "$FOLDER" -name "$FILE"
find /home -name ' ' \ ' ' *test* '\ ' ' '

I don't know why It's adding so many quoting marks

Comment: @MatíasMercado That's because you're still embedding quotes into the value of the variable. Don't do that. Variables hold data, and quotes go *around* data, not *in* data. If you copy Diego's code accurately, it will work.